# Using Android action bar with libGDX

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, libgdx

I'm using libgdx to do some data visualization for an Android app. 
I'm currently integrating a libgdx view inside an Android activity which has an actionbar. This actionbar will have some buttons to expand menus and to update, refresh data and change the libgdx render method.

My question is, is it possible to communicate between the android UI and the libgdx render method? Is implementing a interface like [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx) the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i did something like this with some dialogs.
To integrade android elements
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup
I used public static variables, make a class in your core project like

```
    public class GlobalStuff
   {
      public static boolean Need2Refresh=false;
   }
```

And in your activity on the button click change the value

```
GlobalStuff.Need2Refresh=true;
```

In your Render method you do something like

```
  if(GlobalStuff.Need2Refresh)
    {

    // do what you want to do
    // ex: Refresh();
    GlobalStuff.Need2Refresh=false;  

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try implementing that!